# Clang static analysis doesn't like default parameter for const string&

Tags: c++, static-analysis, clang++, default-parameters

I am getting the following error with clang static analyzer. Any ideas?

```
error: reference to type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const char [1]'
74
    int foo(const std::string& data, const std::string& key = "");
```

header:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    int foo(const std::string& data, const std::string& key = "");
};
```

src:

```
int Test::foo(const std::string& data, const std::string& key)
{
  //stuff
}
```

Comment: very likely a bug, `const char[1]` decays to `const char*` and has a matching ctor.

Comment: Can't see any issues with GCC, Clang, MSVC++ and Intel. https://godbolt.org/z/3xxE3E

Comment: Does the static analyzer calm down if you swap `""` for `{}`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
62
    int foo(const std::string& data, const std::string& key = {});
```

Comment: @kdams15 Did you forget to include the definition of `std::string`?

Comment: What about `std::string("")` instead of `""`?

Comment: @eerorika Wow, that was it. Thank you very much.